# Highchart ticks start point change when categories names are set

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart made with highcharts.js.

The graph works the way I wanted but then if I try to set the categories (programmatically or not) somehitng strange happen, the tick become smaller and move to the centre leaving a big space on the sides of the graph.

**BEFORE:**

[image]

**AFTER:**
[image]

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'graph',
            type: 'area',
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',

        },
        series: [{
            data: [['aa',29.9], ['bb',71.5], ['cc',106.4],['dd', 129.2 ]]
        }],
    });

    // the button handler
    $('#button').click(function() {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['bb', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']);      
    });
});
```

See this JsFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/MaurizioPiccini/d746v/3/

It all happens when you press the button (the categories can be set in the xAxis as well giving the same problem).

Is it possible to have named categories to start and end at the graph extremes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that is also reporteed here: 
http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/highchart-ticks-start-point-change-when-categories-names-are-t29052/

The solution is not to use categorized xAxis but linear or datetime with label formatter like this:

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function(){
           return categories[this.value];
        }
    }
}
```

where `categories` is an array of categories.

It looks like that is the only way to make the chart behave this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use workaround which, updatse your axis with defined min/max value.

```
chart.xAxis[0].update({
        categories: ['bb', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'],
        min: 0.5,
        max: 2.5
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d746v/6/